# Is it possible to solve 3 equations with 2 unknowns in Python (Sympy)

Tags: python, sympy

Currently using sympy to solve the following set of equations:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, nsolve, exp, log, cosh

eq1 = Eq(Vmax**2/Amax * log(cosh(Amax*4.82/Vmax)),40)
eq2 = Eq(Vmax**2/Amax * log(cosh(Amax*2.8/Vmax)),20)

solution = nsolve([eq1, eq2], [Amax, Vmax], [1, 1])
```

I get a solution using this technique. However I have a third equation and I would like to solve for the 2 unknowns using all 3 equations. Is it possible to solve for 2 unknowns with 3 equations in Sympy?

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, nsolve, exp, log, cosh

eq1 = Eq(Vmax**2/Amax * log(cosh(Amax*4.82/Vmax)),40)
eq2 = Eq(Vmax**2/Amax * log(cosh(Amax*2.8/Vmax)),20)
eq3 = Eq(Vmax**2/Amax * log(cosh(Amax*1.65/Vmax)),10)

solution = nsolve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [Amax, Vmax], [1, 1])
```

Trying the code above gives a value error: `ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (0.181941547657103824541 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19) Try another starting point or tweak arguments.`

Can anyone help out or suggest how I can get the values for the 2 unknowns using 3 equations?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I sound naive, but why would you need 3 equations? Shouldn't the first 2 be enough?

Comment: There's no point.  If you get a solution with two equations, then the third equation cannot add anything to the puzzle.

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 yes but to make sure the solution from the first 2 equations actually fits the third equation. Or some sort of combo between 2 of the three equations so it can fit the third.

Comment: Why couldn't you plug in the numbers from the first 2 equations and then see if it works in the 3rd?

Comment: I do but I don't get the right answer. I'm looking for 10 in the third equation but I will get like 9.1. I'm trying to find those 2unkown values that perfectly fit all 3 equations.

Comment: Hmm, if that's the case, then I don't think the equation is solvable. It could be such that the answer is None.

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 Note that if your equations have multiple (or infinite) solutions, then the first solution that appears solving strictly the first two might not solve the third, but some other solution may exist that satisfies all three. Whether or not one does I do not know, but theoretically yes, it might be worth while solving all 3 together.

Comment: @Kraigolas I see. I was thinking linear equations, so that it is true.

Comment: @TimRoberts There is a point. Systems of equations in real-life don't always have the same number of unknowns as the number of equations, e.g. statically indeterminate structures. The third equation just reduces the set of solutions, sometimes to the point that the system doesn't have any solutions.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin spot on thats exactly why Im trying to see if its possible to get sympy to solve 3 equations with 2 unkowns but it looks like that wont be possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly what the error message tells you: there is no solution within the given tolerance.  If you want to check consistency for yourself, then solve the equations in pairs, and then compare the solutions with whatever tolerance or other logic you desire.